# Is there a way to use Assert or Moq.Verify on a Mocked Logger?

Tags: c#, unit-testing, moq

I'm unit testing my OnAuthorization class and i need to test the error cases. Here's an example:

```
Mock<ILogger> mockLog = new Mock<ILogger>();
ILogger log = mockLog.Object;

public override void OnAuthorization(HttpActionContext actionContext)
{
   try 
   {
       //some code
       if (condition)
       {
          //some more code
       }
       else
       {
          throw new Exception("MyMessage");
       }
   }
   catch(Exception ex)
   {
       log.LogError(ex);
   }
}
```

Now, assuming that `condition = false` how can i check that the right exception was thrown in an UnitTest method?

I thought about using `log.Verify` or `Assert.That` but i don't see how i should use them to achieve my goal
Any Ideas?

p.s. I'm working on a huge project, and I'm not the only one working on it, so i should avoid modifying the code unless it's really unavoidable.

Comment: You could use `Assert.Throws<Exception>(...)`.

Comment: Off-topic, but: you can include `using static NUnit.Framework.Assert;` to get rid of redundant `Assert`s. The above example coud then be re-written as `Throws<Exception>(...)` (assuming you are using NUnit).

Comment: I don't think you can use `Assert.Throws` when the code **catches** the exception.

Comment: _"how can i check that the right exception was thrown in an UnitTest method?"_ - look for "MyMessage" in the logger?

Comment: Write a custom ILogger implementation that saves all log events Internally. Inject that In your tests and the assert the contents...LogError, etc are likely the extension method versions which you cannot mock/verify. So that's prob your best bet

Comment: That was exactly what i was looking for. Thanks @PeterCsala! I also think the solution proposed by @pinkfloydx33 is viable, just much more complicated for what i need. Thanks you all for your time!

Comment: @FrancescoCusumano Do you need assertion against all the logger invocations?

Comment: @PeterCsala No I don't, I just needed to verify that the correct exception was thrown, so only one particular logger invocation matters